# Reading a PDF back from an iFrame?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik

I have a PDF document that is getting generated on the fly, and rendered on the fly to an iFrame within a radwindow.  Basically the document is already largely prepopulated, however the user will still have a chunk of information that they are required to enter.  I've found a good amount of information about sending a pdf TO an iframe, but not much information about going the other way.  I have a button within the radwindow that can access the iframe object, however I'm somewhat lost as to where to go from there.

EDIT: The PDF is an editable form.  I'm trying to pull back the entire PDF document as is, after the client side makes their entries to the form.

Comment: Do you have control over the code within the iframe?

Comment: The Iframe is where the pdf is actually written out to, using a `Response.BinaryWrite` so code can't really be executed from within the Iframe itself after the PDF is displayed, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: If no code "runs" in the iframe - why have the iframe at all? What is then all this about "chunk of information that they are required to enter"? Is it information the users writes into editable fields in the pdf? Because if so - then that happens on the client and not "in the iframe".

Comment: The IFrame is being used just as a container to display the PDF.  You are correct that the users are in fact adding information into a form PDF.  I'm trying to pull back the PDF after they've edited it via a button on the radwindow, and that's where I'm somewhat stuck. I understand that it's not really "in the iframe" but rather on the PDF that's served to the client side.  I should have been a little more clear on that in the initial question.

Comment: Are you sure that's even possible? When the user edits text in a PDF, he'll have to save it. That save happens on the client machine in what ever application the user might use to handle PDFs and therefore outside the scope of browsers?

Comment: That's what I was hoping to accomplish, being that I'm finding very little information about people even attempting it, I'm not certain if it is or not. I was hoping that someone tried to implement this and was actually more successful than I've been thus far.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only way to do this is having the user upload/submit his changed PDF via an appropriate function. I see no other way around this; other than of course not having the editing happening in the PDF but in a online form instead and then you can "print" the completed PDF.

Comment: I'll leave the question here, in case anyone else has actually attempted to do this, and has gotten anywhere with it.

Comment: As per what was described in the comments, I ended up using postbacks through the PDF's themselves along with 1 pixel fields to store data required to identify the documents. It's a little hacky, but functional. I'm leaving this as an actual answer as this is as close to a real solution to the problem I originally had. This has been up and running for close to 4 years in this manner, and thus far hasn't caused any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to send the file to the user so they can edit it locally and instruct them to upload it.

The `content-disposition` header with value `attachment` can help with the first task and you can use RadAsyncUpload to upload it: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx.

I am not aware of ways to tap into the PDF viewer plugin the browsers use to show the PDF. Perhaps there is API from Adobe or some other third party plugin but that would rely on them and is out of your control.

Perhaps the JS PDF viewer from FireFox has something: https://mozillalabs.com/en-US/pdfjs/ but I don't know how stable and usable it is.

Comment: It looks like PDF.js might eventually be able to do what I'm looking for, however it seems like it's pretty far from complete for the moment.  Although I don't want to go this route, it seems I may have no choice but to have the client save the pdf on their end after making changes then reupload it.

Comment: I think people are used to working like this with documents that need input, so a small instructional message should suffice.
Another option is to just create a form with the needed fields and do the insertion into the PDF on the server with your code, if that's an option. In this manner the PDF will never go to the user at all and you will still have the input.

Comment: I'd thought about doing it that way, but there's a number of different pdf's that can be displayed, depending on the parameters, and there's potential for more documents to be added to the list as well....for now, I'm just having the users save locally then upload back with an upload control.  It's really not quite what I'm after, but it's good enough for the time being.

Comment: I've now got something a little closer to what I was after.  I've edited the PDF documents with Acrobat, and added a submit button to each document.  Basically this forces a POST to a URL that I indicate.  I grab the POST data on the other end using `Request.BinaryRead()` and can process the data as per normal.  It's still not exactly perfect, but prevents the end users from having to save the document on their end and re-load it back into the system.

Comment: I know this is now the 3rd post in a row, but I just stumbled across the fact that the above solution does NOT correctly work in all browsers by default, for example Chrome and Firefox have their own built in (but not quite compliant) pdf viewers that don't deal so well with form submitted PDF's.  This can be worked around by changing the default viewer (http://helpx.adobe.com/livecycle/kb/xfa-forms-firefox-chrome.html) the process is stated to be for xfa forms, but also fixes this issue.  I figured this should be noted in case anyone attempts to replicate what I am doing.